# calling onRequestPermissionsResult inside of android library with activity from main app

Tags: android, android-permissions

so i am writing an Android library which will get the gps coordinates from the cellphone. now ofcourse for this i need permissions, So i got:

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(contexts, ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(contexts, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(contexts, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, (new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}), MY_LOCATION_REQUEST_CODE);
        Log.e("permissionsBlock", "Ask for permissions");
        return;
}
```

i get this working perfectlly as i want it to. it asks for my permission i give it and it works.

Now the problem: it does not auto run my other code once it has permission so i searched and found i should use **onRequestPermissionsResult**. so i implemented it but nothing happens because it is inside my library, if i post it in my Application it get's triggered but not if i put it in my library. anybody has an idea on how to fix this?

thanks for your time.

Comment: delegate the response from the activity to your library. Or better yet: let the library user handle the permission and tell him not to call your lib until the permission is granted

Comment: thanks for the fast response, and how would i delegate this? and that is what i did not wanted to do, i wanted to do all the permission stuff because i want it as low step in as possible.

Comment: My library for handling permissions may come handy to you. https://github.com/nabinbhandari/Android-Permissions

Comment: thx @NabinBhandari used your library and works like a charm

Comment: I am happy that my library worked for you. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the library from @NabinBhandari simplifies this process A LOT. If you have a similar problem, give it a try.

https://github.com/nabinbhandari/Android-Permissions